# while reading xml file line by line need to update some tag based on class name in java

Tags: java

i am reading one xml file to another file it is fine but while reading i am checking condition for updation of one statement but it is not updating, please suggest me on this

```
public class PutMesageDebugger {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:/PutMessageDebugger/Sub_Workflow_HSS.xml"), "UTF-8"));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:/PutMessageDebugger/tempSub_Workflow_HSS.xml"), "UTF-8"));

     String line = null;

     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){                   
     //System.out.println("line"+ line);

      //System.out.println(line.contains("<Process-Node"));
        /*System.out.println(line.contains("<Class-Name>com.hp.ov.activator.mwfm.component.builtin.PutMessage</Class-Name>"));
           System.out.println(!line.contains("inactive=true"));
                         */
         if ( line.contains("<Class-Name==com.hp.ov.activator.mwfm.component.builtin.PutMessage")){
             line = line.replaceAll("<Process-Node","<Process-Node inactive=\"true\" ");

                  }

             writer.write(line + "\n");



                  }

              reader.close();
              writer.close();

           }
```

Comment: I would strongly avoid reading XML line by line to start with. Why not read it *as an XML document*? At the moment your code is *very* sensitive to the exact format, which appears to contain a rather bizarre element name. If it's actually valid XML, treat it as such. You may be able to just use XSLT to perform the transformation you want, in fact.

Comment: Hi Jon,
xml transaformation is fine but in that if  condition 
if(line.contains("<Process-Node") for this one it is updating

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to parse XML like that. You should use a XML library, which takes care of white-space handling and many other things for you. Take a look at the `javax.xml` package.

If all you want to do is to add the `inactive="true"` attribute  to the `ProcessNode` element, you could go for XSLT. There are many resources on how to do that, e.g. [add attribute example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824843/adding-attribute-to-the-node)

Comment: can you share any example of XSLT

Comment: not for all processNode tags only class name in some put message

Comment: inactive="true " is not for all proccesNodes only class name is equal to putmessage

Comment: The link provided shows an example. If you want me to write the transformation for you, you will at least have to post your XML document instance.

Comment: how to share my xml its too long

Comment: share the relevant fragment!

Comment: <Process-Node>
         <Name>PutMessage42</Name>
         <Action>
            <Class-Name>com.hp.ov.activator.mwfm.component.builtin.PutMessage</Class-Name>
            <Param name="message" value="rollback success is %s"/>
            <Param name="queue" value="info"/>
            <Param name="param0" value="constant_order_status_rollback_failure"/>
         </Action>
         <Next-Node>Update the sub order status &quot;rollback failure&quot;</Next-Node>
      </Process-Node>

Comment: like this <process-node inactive="true">to add