# How to add attribute to XML using xchange

Tags: xml, xpath

Suppose I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="pathto/xsd/meta.xsd">
    <baar name="metaName"></baar>
</foo>
```

How to add attribute `visible="false"` to the node `<baar>`?

I tried the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<xchange xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="pathto/xsd/xchange.xsd" location="@super">     
    <insert xpath="/foo/baar/@visible" visible="false">  
    </insert>  
</xchange>
```

But it does not work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824843/adding-attribute-to-the-node

Comment: You should state what `xchange` is because it's not well-known, and XPath alone does not *manipulate* XML; it *selects* from XML.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/foo/baar">
        <baar visible="false">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </baar>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the explanation [adding attribute to the node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824843/adding-attribute-to-the-node)

Comment: hmmm in the project, is exchange / xpath is using and not xslt

Comment: As @kjhughes says, you should explain what xchange is. XPath is a syntax to refer to elements in a XML document and does not manipulate XML.