# Install4j: How to add an attributes in the XML node using the built in actions?

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to add new attributes in the XML node using the built in actions?

I had tried replacing whole node using the action "insert XML fragment into XML files" to add the attribute to XML node.

I just wanted an attributes to be added, instead of replacing the whole XML node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of install4j 7, this it is not possible to add just attributes. You would have to add a "Apply an XSLT transform" action for this purpose.

See

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4825010/936832

for details on the required XSLT.